# C program of inventory, while loop for beer inventory

Tags: c, computer-science

I cannot seem to stay in the while loop.  I enter the ID code and the number purchased or sold the first time and it exits even though I asked that it only exits if -1 is entered for the code.  Is there something simple here needing correction or is this too extensive?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    int inv1, inv2, inv3, inv4, amount, code;

    printf ("Beer brand IDs \n");
    printf ("1. Piels \n");
    printf ("2. Coors \n");
    printf ("3. Bud \n");
    printf ("4. Iron City \n");

    printf ("Inventory at beginning of week \n");

    printf ("1. Piels:  ");
    scanf ("%d", &inv1);
    printf ("2. Coors:  ");
    scanf ("%d", &inv2);
    printf ("3. Bud:  ");
    scanf ("%d", &inv3);
    printf ("4. Iron City:  ");
    scanf ("%d", &inv4);

    while (code != -1) {
        printf ("ID:  ");
        scanf ("%d", &code);
        printf ("amount requested or subtracted:  ");
        scanf ("%d", &amount);

        if (code == 1) {
            inv1 = inv1 + amount;
        }
        else if (code == 2) {
            inv2 = inv2 + amount;
        }
        else if (code == 3) {
            inv3 = inv3 + amount;
        }
        else if (code == 4) {
            inv4 = inv4 + amount;
        }
        else (code == -1); {
            break;
            }
            printf ("End of week for Piels:  %d", inv1);
            printf ("End of week for Coors:  %d", inv2);
            printf ("End of week for Bud:  %d", inv3);
            printf ("End of week for Iron City: %d", inv4);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Remove the ; at the end of `else (code == -1);`

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of technical logic issues with your code. To begin with `code` is used ***uninitialized*** when entering the loop. Your compiler should be warning you about the problem. Make sure you have ***warnings enabled*** (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`) every time you compile and do not accept code that compiles with warnings. (you can also add `-pedantic` to see additional warnings)

You have a garbled `else`. `else (code == -1);` is incorrect. It appears you intended `else { code = 1; break; }`. Note the `code` variable is not needed at all. Simply use `while (1)` or `for (;;)` to loop until you `break` out of the loop.

Your prompts say `subtracted`, but you are adding within your code (e.g. `inv4 = inv4 + amount;`). Simply use the `-=` operator to actually subtract `amount` for each `ID`.

Always, always check the `return` of every call to `scanf`. That is the only way you can ***validate*** you receive an actual value from the user and are not attempting to process garbage from that point onward (it also protects against an endless loop if your user enters something other than a decimal)

Finally, your `"End of week"` `printf` statements should be ***outside*** the loop, not within it. Here is a short example of what it appears you intended with your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int inv1, inv2, inv3, inv4;
    inv1 = inv2 = inv3 = inv4 = 0;  /* initialize values */

    printf ("Beer brand IDs \n");
    printf ("1. Piels\n2. Coors\n3. Bud\n4. Iron City\n\n");

    printf ("Inventory at beginning of week\n");

    printf ("1. Piels    :  ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &inv1) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("2. Coors    :  ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &inv2) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("3. Bud      :  ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &inv3) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("4. Iron City:  ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &inv4) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (1) {
        int amount = 0, code = 0;
        printf ("ID ('q' to quit):  ");
        if (scanf ("%d", &code) != 1) break;
        printf ("amount requested or subtracted:  ");
        if (scanf ("%d", &amount) != 1) break;

        if (code == 1)
            inv1 -= amount;
        else if (code == 2)
            inv2 -= amount;
        else if (code == 3)
            inv3 -= amount;
        else if (code == 4)
            inv4 -= amount;
        else
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: ID out of range.\n");
    }

    printf ("\nEnd of week for Piels     :  %d\n", inv1);
    printf ("End of week for Coors     :  %d\n", inv2);
    printf ("End of week for Bud       :  %d\n", inv3);
    printf ("End of week for Iron City :  %d\n", inv4);

    return (0);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rfmt
Beer brand IDs
1. Piels
2. Coors
3. Bud
4. Iron City

Inventory at beginning of week
1. Piels    :  10
2. Coors    :  10
3. Bud      :  10
4. Iron City:  10
ID ('q' to quit):  1
amount requested or subtracted:  2
ID ('q' to quit):  2
amount requested or subtracted:  3
ID ('q' to quit):  3
amount requested or subtracted:  4
ID ('q' to quit):  4
amount requested or subtracted:  5
ID ('q' to quit):  q

End of week for Piels     :  8
End of week for Coors     :  7
End of week for Bud       :  6
End of week for Iron City :  5
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.